# VBA Send message to whatsapp group

Tags: excel, vba, whatsapp

Is it possible to send a message to a whatsapp group using vba?

I can send to a phone number but I was wondering if is possible to a group.

Comment: Whatsapp has a supported [Url Scheme](https://fvdm.com/code/note-whatsapp-url-scheme) that you can use to launch the app and send messages. There does not appear to be any way to send a message to a group, as their url scheme only supports single contacts. To launch a URL from VBA use the [Shell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/shell-function) Function

Comment: @Toddleson I understand. Thanks for the info.